# What is the optimal time to train in order to see gains in size and strength?

Tags: weightlifting, strength, recovery, strength-training, programs

I am a 21 year old male, currently on my own program that can be found [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10342/how-can-i-improve-my-training-program-to-become-leaner-and-increase-strength). It is quite intense and I was wondering what the optimal time to train for **strength** would be?

**Please Note:** I lift moderately heavy weights (in the region of 100Kg for deads, squats and bench)

Would it be:

- A) when I have no aching left in my muscles, indicating to me that they have fully recovered.

or

- B) when there is still a slight ache or tiredness present within the muscle.

Comment: [Importance of Rest Days](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/96/3941) is related.

Comment: @Informaficker - I understand the importance of rest days, but that isn't the understand I am after. I may have rested but could still ache, there fore will it have a detrimental effect on my strength gain

Comment: [Do you need to “feel the burn” to become stronger?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/811/3941) and [Is there a relation between muscle soreness and muscle progress?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7771/3941) are also related.

Comment: Title of question is misleading. It feels like it's going to be a time of day question, but it's not. Moreover, the actual question has been answered several times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes approximately 36 hours for the muscle fibres to recover, but even after 36 hours of intense training you will still be able to feel the aching in your muscles ..

If you're training with a split program, it's better to do exercises in different muscle groups everyday, and then have 2 recovery days per week, with no exercises.

If you are training with the same exercises everyday, it's better to recover every second day.

So the answer to your question is a mix of both A and B.

Comment: Do you have any resources available to back up your claims?

Comment: @Informaficker Don't hound the new guy; not every answer needs references.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann My comment was out of interest, the 36 hours seemed as he might actually have read about that somewhere and might be able to cite from his sources.

Comment: @Informaficker My answer was based on the McMaster research. I know that the research was made with skilled bodybuilders, and of course the recovery time variates from person to another, but it's better to take the precautions.